# TDD to design a service using a data repository

Tags: spring, unit-testing, jpa, interface, tdd

How would you design a service class, that might use a data repository beneath doing TDD? For example, if we want to define an interface UserStorageService and UserStorageService#save(User user) implementation that saves user to some database through jpa repository interface? Should I mock specific save or saveAndFlush or similar JpaReposiotory's methods if I don't even know which one's I will be actually calling?

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring's Test Support instead of mocking `save` or `saveAndFlush`. Then annotate your Test with `@Transactional`, Spring will start the transaction with your Test Case and role it back when the test case is finished. (Of course you must not start a new Transation (for example with `propgation=NEW`) in the code that is invoked by the test).

@See [Spring Reference Chapter 14.5.6 Transaction management (Test)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testcontext-tx)

Comment: So you are suggesting integration tests for such cases?

Comment: Yes, when the Repositoy part is a very relevant part of Service Method under test, then it would be useless to test it with mocks that remove the most of the relevant part - if the repository is not relevant, then I would implement an Fake (not mock) implementation of the repository interface and use this for the test.